# A method to update the image in a python program on fulfilling a certain condition (Tkinter and PIL used)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am not well versed in Tkinter and have use multiple sites to create this program for a project. It is a quiz program that uses a GUI interface to display a banner above the questions. I require a method to update the banner based on when someone achieves a full/ low score. Also I would like to know if I need to remove the PIL for a Label to house the image. All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from PIL import ImageTk,Image


class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correctLetter):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctLetter = correctLetter

    def check(self, letter, view):
        global right
        if(letter == self.correctLetter):
            label2= Label(view, text="Right!")
            right += 1
        else:
            label2= Label(view, text="Wrong!")
        label2.pack()
        view.after(1000, lambda *args: self.unpackView(view))


    def getView(self, window):
        view = Frame(window)
        label1 = Label(view, text=self.question)
        button_a = Button(view, text=self.answers[0], command=lambda *args: self.check("A", view))
        button_b = Button(view, text=self.answers[1], command=lambda *args: self.check("B", view))
        button_c = Button(view, text=self.answers[2], command=lambda *args: self.check("C", view))
        button_d = Button(view, text=self.answers[3], command=lambda *args: self.check("D", view))
        label1.pack()
        button_a.pack()
        button_b.pack()
        button_c.pack()
        button_d.pack()
        return view
    
    def unpackView(self, view):
        view.pack_forget()
        askQuestion()

def askQuestion():
    global questions, window, index, button, right, number_of_questions 
    if(len(questions) == index + 1):
        Label(window, text="Thank you for answering the questions. " + str(right) + " of " + str(number_of_questions) + " questions answered right").pack()
        return
    button.pack_forget()
    index += 1
    questions[index].getView(window).pack()

questions = []
file = open('C:\\Users\\tjohn\\Desktop\\Art Intergration\\Comp\\questions.txt', "r")
line = file.readline()
while(line != ""):
    questionString = line
    answers = []
    for i in range (4):
        answers.append(file.readline())

    correctLetter = file.readline()
    correctLetter = correctLetter[:-1]
    questions.append(Question(questionString, answers, correctLetter))
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
index = -1
right = 0
number_of_questions = len(questions)

window = Tk()
C = Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=350, width=800)
C.pack()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\Users\\tjohn\\Desktop\\quiz.png"))  
C.create_image(800/2, 350/2, anchor=CENTER, image=img)

button = Button(window, text="Start", command=askQuestion)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which function or where do you want to update?

Comment: I want to update the image used in the Canvas at the end of the program.... Im guessing that it would be done in the function definition of askQuestion() when the function prints the Thank you message....

Comment: Try changing the initial canvas image as `C.create_image(800/2, 350/2, anchor=CENTER, image=img,tag='pic')` and when you want to update it, say `c.itemconfigure('pic',image=newpic)`

Comment: Umm I tried this method but just to be clear, is there any prerequisite to using itemconfigure like any module to be imported or any new code to be inserted in any part?

Comment: I may have done the code wrong but I get a long list of errors...This is where I put it  `def askQuestion():
    global questions, window, index, button, right, number_of_questions 
    if(len(questions) == index + 1):
        Label(window, text="Thank you for answering the questions. " + str(right) + " of " + str(number_of_questions) + " questions answered right").pack()
        if right==number_of_questions:
            C.itemconfigure('pic',image="C:\\Users\\tjohn\\Desktop\\Congrats.png")
        return
    button.pack_forget()
    index += 1`

Comment: Srry for the bad formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer because too long for comments:

Add a tag to canvas image, like:

```
window = Tk()
C = Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=350, width=800)
C.pack()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\Users\\tjohn\\Desktop\\quiz.png"))  
C.create_image(800/2, 350/2, anchor=CENTER, image=img,tags='pic')
```

Later inside the function say:

```
def askQuestion():
    global questions, window, index, button, right, number_of_questions 
    if(len(questions) == index + 1):
        Label(window, text="Thank you for answering the questions. " + str(right) + " of " + str(number_of_questions) + " questions answered right").pack()
        new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('New path'))
        c.itemconfigure('pic',image=new_img)
        return
    button.pack_forget()
    index += 1
    questions[index].getView(window).pack()
```

`itemconfigure()` is a method of `tkinter.Canvas` there is no need for further import of anything.

Not sure if this will work, cant run your code, take a look and let me know.

Comment: It certainly updates...however the new image doesnt line up with how the previous image does....Both are of the same size.... Is there a place that requires Anchor again?

Comment: Thats strange, i think it will just replace, im not sure as to why? Maybe include a screenshot or ask a new Q